# Problem with open stream in Xcode 14 & iOS 16 - Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push Connectivity instead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

I have problem with Xcode 14 & iOS 16.
When I start the app, the app crashes immediately.
I know the problem is in:

```
private var inputStream: InputStream!
private var outputStream: OutputStream!
```

create stream:

```
        var readStream:  Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
        
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, connectionConfiguration.host, connectionConfiguration.port, &readStream, &writeStream)

        inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        
        inputStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL, forKey: .socketSecurityLevelKey)
        outputStream.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.negotiatedSSL, forKey: .socketSecurityLevelKey)
        
        
        inputStream.setProperty(StreamNetworkServiceTypeValue.voIP, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.networkServiceType)
        outputStream.setProperty(StreamNetworkServiceTypeValue.voIP, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.networkServiceType)
```

configure streams:

```
        inputStream!.delegate = self
        outputStream!.delegate = self
        inputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        outputStream!.schedule(in: .main, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
```

when I open stream I got crash.

```
inputStream!.open()
outputStream!.open()
```

I need this streams to connect with backend.
Info from Xcode:

```
libsp.dylib`spd_checkin_socket.cold.1:
    0x21c764464 <+0>:  adrp   x8, 144598
    0x21c764468 <+4>:  adrp   x9, 0
    0x21c76446c <+8>:  add    x9, x9, #0xa3f            ; "Linked against modern SDK, VOIP socket will not wake. Use Local Push Connectivity instead"
    0x21c764470 <+12>: str    x9, [x8, #0x390]
->  0x21c764474 <+16>: brk    #0x1
```

Anyone know what it is and how to fix it?

I was searching for this and couldn't find any help for this problem anywhere.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show more code?  How are you creating the sockets and streams?

Comment: @Paulw11 Done, I Added how I create streams

Comment: You cannot use `StreamNetworkServiceTypeValue.voIP` any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer create sockets with [StreamNetworkServiceTypeValue.voIP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/streamnetworkservicetypevalue/1412047-voip)

This service type was deprecated in iOS 10.  In the iOS 14 SDK, using this service type results in a crash.

Comment: But what is the alternative or workaround?

Comment: Callkit and voip pushes are the replacement; a "voip" push will launch an app, even if it has been terminated, but the app must immediately report an incoming call via callkit. If your app was trying to keep a network connection open for some other purpose then there is no alternative. Persistent network connections are not supported on iOS.